# Equal geom point size in legend in multiple plots with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to equalise the size of geom_points throughout multiple plots, so that they are easily comparable?

ie. I want the size of a 100 value to be equal throughout the plots, regardless of the minimum and maximum value that makes up the size values. As seen below, the size of geom_points are the same, but they represent different values.

[image]

[image]

```
graph <- ggplot(mar, aes(x=long, y=lat)) + xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
graph  + theme_grey() + geom_point(aes(size=distance$NEAR_DIST)) + scale_size_area() + labs(size = "Distance from predicted LCP Roman\nroad to known Roman road (m)")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve that as follows:

```
df1 =data.frame(x=1:20,y=runif(20,1,10),size=runif(20,1,10))
df2 =data.frame(x=1:20,y=runif(20,1,10),size=runif(20,31,40))

maximum = max(c(df1$size,df2$size))

graph <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y,size=size)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_size_area(limits=c(1,maximum))

graph2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y,size=size)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_size_area(limits=c(1,maximum))
```

[image][image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Quick question: Do you know how I can change the 'breaks' that occur? In particular, to specifically choose the breaks that I want the data to be broken into, as well as when visualised in the legend.

Comment: In the [Documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_size.html), I see there is a parameter called 'breaks'. So you could add that parameter as follows: `scale_size_area(limits=c(1,maximum),breaks=c(1,5,10,15,0,25,30))`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Upvoted answer. Really useful!

Comment: Thanks, and glad I could help!